# Searching for a method to get Wireless Access Point information programmatically

Tags: mobile, network-programming, location, ibeacon

I've been investigating a way of tracking a device's location in a building, at first I was intending to use iBeacons. However I have been since told that it must be done by monitoring access points and looking for the MAC address of that device.

I can't seem to find any generic sort of library or API that can hook into an access point and give me details. Infact I don't even know where to start looking which is making it even harder.

Has anybody had dealings with this and could point me in the right direction? Any programming language acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written software from scratch to do exactly this, but to my knowledge, no frameworks are available.

The basic steps are:

1. Get a number of small, low-cost computers (Raspberry Pis work nicely) to act as sensors that do WiFi scanning in promiscuous mode, collecting unique macs and detection times.  On Linux, you can use C or Java software to collect these records.
2. Write the info from the sensors to a server, including the sensor identifier so you know where each device was detected.
3. Write lots of code to crunch the numbers.

You should be aware of three big issues:

1. Mobile devices aren't always detectable on WiFi.  If they are asleep, or simply not communicating, you will not detect them.  On iOS the best you can hope for is detections every minute or so if the device is not locked and not actively using WiFi.
2. On iOS 8+, mac addresses are scrambled under certain conditions,boften making it impossible to track unique devices.
3. Building the above from scratch is a lot of work.  Think several man months for even a basic system.

I know you were asked to build it this way and not with beacons, but beacons do provide a much simpler path forward if you can ensure an app on each device and can revisit this design constraint.

Comment: Thanks, your comment confirms my thoughts, it is going to be too large of a task to do in the time frame I have.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do this with iBeacons.

But :

On IOS 8 , when u try in anyway to get mac adress from a device , you obtain this value : 02:00:00:00:00:00.

The best way to get an unique identifier for a device is to use the identifierForVendor method form UIDevice.

Like this :

```
UIDevice *device = [[UIDevice alloc]init]; 
NSString *uniqueIdForDevice= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device identifierForVendor]]; 
NSLog(@"%@",uniqueIdForDevice);
```

That gives you an ID that's unique for that device for your company.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you it will help, looks like IBeacons is the way forward now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the constraints are on your particular design but there are existing systems that allow you to get the kind of monitoring I think you're looking for. As davidgyoung writes, there are a few technical challenges that exist at OS level that will be present in whatever wi-fi solution to choose (e.g. iOS MAC address rotation). That aside, you might get some value from looking at solutions from Wi-fi hardware manufacturers like Cisco: https://meraki.cisco.com/solutions/cmx . They have a pre-built platform for visitor data (i.e. showing you where phones are in buildings/spaces). I think all the major wi-fi hardware manufacturers have something similar now and Cisco are likely to be top-end. From memory, Aruba were much cheaper (I'm going back ~10 months).

There are also software providers like Euclid Analytics ( http://euclidanalytics.com ) who build on top of the hardware and API's of providers like Cisco to provide visitor info like I think you want.

This isn't an exhaustive list as I'm writing this from memory but hopefully a bit of Googling based on the above should give you a better chance of success than rolling your own.

Good luck,
James

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do indoor location services, then I would recommend checking out Cisco Connected Mobile Experience software.

You can try it free.

Based on my analysis, it is the best solution out there. I am biased because I work there. But, I do competitive analysis and have yet to find anything I think works better.

Comment: Also- you get get a bunch of tutorial information and links to try it for free here:

https://developer.cisco.com/site/cmx-mobility-services/